# How will Philae's power failure affect Rosetta's mission?

Tags: mission-design, rosetta, failure, philae

With Philae dead on the comet, how will Rosetta's mission change? Obviously there isn't anything more that the lander can do, so Rosetta doesn't have to use its time and resources trying to wake it up. Will Rosetta be moved into positions or given tasks that it otherwise wouldn't if Philae was still functional? How is Philae's power failure going to affect the mission as a whole?

Answer (score 4):

Philae's [primary mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philae_%28spacecraft%29) was planned to last for a week, with possible extensions.
This primary mission is considered successful:

> Prior to falling silent, the lander was able to transmit all science data gathered during the First Science Sequence.

Has Philae landed as planned...

> Had Philae landed at the planned site of Agilkia in November 2014, its mission would probably have ended in March 2015 due to the higher temperatures of that location as solar heating increased.

So the mission plan already counted on Philae not being available for most of last year. They've made some changes to try and contact Philae at regular intervals, until the comet came too close to perihelion for Rosetta to operate in radio range of Philae.

To summarize, no. Nothing will change.